# Differences between .dump and .sql in pg_dump PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, format, pg-restore

I'm trying to take a backup of schema using pg_dump like,

```
$ pg_dump -U ganapathy -n hotel_management > ganapathy_schema.dump
```

It create the backup, But I can't restore it using `pg_restore`. It give error like this,

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid
>   archive

Then I try to take the backup with .`sql` extension like,

```
$ pg_dump -U ganapathy -n hotel_management > ganapathy_schema.sql
```

But It also gives the same error.

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid
>   archive

After that I try to take a backup by specifying the format like, `-Fc` in both `.dump` and `.sql` extensions.
Then I try to restore it. It restored successfully.

So now my doubt is,

> What is the differences between the extensions of .dump and .sql in
>   pg_dump in PostgreSQL?

Because both needs to specify the format.

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: As a last resort, you can always read the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html - 3rd and 4th paragraphs of the Description section.

Answer (score 15):

The file extension means nothing. At all. It's just a part of a file name.

If you want a custom-format dump for use with `pg_restore` use `-Fc` as an argument to `pg_dump`.

`pg_dump` defaults to generating SQL-format dumps for use with `psql`.

See the manual for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

## see your actual names in the Cluster column

`pg_lsclusters`

## restore a DB backup dump with

`pg_restore -h HOST -p PORT -U SUPERUSERNAME -C -d postgres DBtoRESTORE.dump`